# What is the right process for patching a release build on the ROS2 build farm?

Tags: ros2

I have a couple of packages that have recently been released on the ROS2 build farm: [`reach`](https://github.com/ros-industrial/reach) and [`reach_ros`](https://github.com/ros-industrial/reach_ros2). `reach` is nominally a "ROS-independent" library that currently has no dependency on ROS2 or `ament`, but it attempts to build and install a Python bindings library. Currently this Python bindings library is being installed to an incorrect directory because I am not using the [`ament_get_python_install_dir`](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/571379977af23528fb805f812c0e20466e140fb1/ament_cmake_python/cmake/ament_get_python_install_dir.cmake#L22) function, which was introduced in ROS2 Humble.

I would like to apply a patch to the release branch for the `reach` `humble` build, that introduces the dependency on `ament` and leverages the function above. I only want to add this patch to the release build and not to the source code (so as not to introduce a dependency on ROS for this package).

Is the correct process for doing this simply pushing the patch to the [`patches/release/humble/reach` branch of the release repository](https://github.com/ros2-gbp/reach-release/tree/patches/release/humble/reach)?

I was able to do this (apparently successfully) for the [`patches/release/noetic/reach` branch](https://github.com/ros2-gbp/reach-release/tree/patches/release/noetic/reach). However, I was not able to do a similar thing for a different patch on the [`reach_ros` release repo](https://github.com/ros2-gbp/reach_ros2-release/commits/patches/release/humble/reach_ros) (see the history of the branch). In the case of the `reach_ros` release repo, the patch was somehow deleted (possibly by a subsequent call to `bloom-release`).

TLDR: what is the correct process for applying a patch to a release track of a library being built on the ROS2 build farm?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial section at http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/ReleaseThirdParty#Adding_an_Install_Rule_as_a_Patch has the basic workflow for patching software for release. The `patches/*` branches in bloom are essentially an "internal" implementation detail and they are updated when bloom picks up changes to the `release/*`, `debian/*`, or `rpm/*` branches.

In your case the past releases of your package will serve as having completed the `git bloom-release ...` step and you can proceed after that.

In fact, if you commit and push the changes to your `release/*` branch and run `bloom-release ...` again it will pick up and apply the changes for you without running `git bloom-patch export`.